# How to get image from the database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I didn't make the image into binary form, but want to get that image data from database now.
So can you give so idea about that. 
I have done like below to insert image:

```
FileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = @":D\";
dialog.Filter = "(*.jpg;*.gif;*.jpeg;*.bmp)| *.jpg; *.gif; *.jpeg; *.bmp";
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    imagename = dialog.FileName;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imagename);
}
dialog = null;
```

Then it also store in database but now I have to retrive the image in next form how can I do?

Comment: Images are almost always in binary form. If you are storing an image in a database you are almost certainly storing it in binary. Your question isn't very clear. Can you be more specific, maybe give some code examples?

Comment: How is the image stored in the database (code sample preferable)?

Comment: "i didn't make the image into binary form" - so; how exactly **is** it stored in the db? what field type? and what data access tools are you using?

Comment: if you are using BLOB, you can retrieve your image as byte[] and convert it to Image.

Comment: i m using visual studio 2008 with sql server 2005....

Comment: @devilsmind, post your code that stores the image in the database!

Comment: OK, so you just edited a question that's over a year old and all you did is remove a character instead of posting the code the commenters asked for?

Comment: I know this is an old question but for other people reading, please don't store images in the database. I have never come across a good use for it, it takes up far too much db space and slows down everything immensely. Even if you have securtity issues or automatically generated images, there are better ways in every circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int O_id =Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strCn);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BLOBTest (BLOBData, O_id) VALUES (@BLOBData,'"+O_id+"')", cn);
            String strBLOBFilePath = textBox1.Text;//Modify this path as needed.


            //Read jpg into file stream, and from there into Byte array.
            FileStream fsBLOBFile = new FileStream(strBLOBFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Byte[] bytBLOBData = new Byte[fsBLOBFile.Length];
            fsBLOBFile.Read(bytBLOBData, 0, bytBLOBData.Length);
            fsBLOBFile.Close();

            //Create parameter for insert command and add to SqlCommand object.
            SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter("@BLOBData", SqlDbType.VarBinary, bytBLOBData.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false,
                        0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, bytBLOBData);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            //Open connection, execute query, and close connection.
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Picture has been uploaded");
            cn.Close();
```

Comment: If you intended to update your question with more information, you have the option to do that. Does this post answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection connection = null;
try
 {
 Byte[] imgByte = null;
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
{
 HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
 File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
 }
 connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings         
 "ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());

 connection.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(title,image) VALUES(@theTitle, @theImage) SELECT     
@@IDENTITY";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theTitle", txtTitle.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theImage", imgByte);
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
 lblStatus.Text = String.Format("ID is {0}", id);

 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/DisplayImg.ashx?id=" + id;
}
{
lblStatus.Text = "There was an error";
}
finally
{
 connection.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming you stored the image as a BLOB field in your database, the following code retrieves the BLOB field data, creates a memory stream and loads a `Bitmap` from the memory stream:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = ...)
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM <tableName> WHERE ...", conn)
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] picData= reader["Picture"] as byte[] ?? null;

            if (picData!= null)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picData))
                {
                    // Load the image from the memory stream. How you do it depends
                    // on whether you're using Windows Forms or WPF.
                    // For Windows Forms you could write:
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;


using System.Drawing;

using System.Data;

using System.IO;

using System.Drawing.Imaging;


public void Save_Image(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Create a byte[] from the input file

    int len = Upload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] pic = new byte[len];
    Upload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read (pic, 0, len);

    // Insert the image into the database

    SqlConnection connection = new
 SqlConnection (@"server=abc\.SQLEXPRESS;database=Storage;uid=sa;pwd=sa");

    try
    {
        connection.Open ();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("insert into Image " 
          + "(Picture) values (@pic)", connection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add ("@pic", pic);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();

    }
    finally 
    {
        connection.Close ();
    }
}
```

we are only storing byte-image into table name"Image"
which contains only one column. 
Storing byte-image into database consume a lot of database-size
for large image-storing and retrieving specific image from database
using search  takes longer time for processing.This causes 
low performance and storage problem.